# Angular build not working on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I am trying to run my AngularJS front-end on server. I am using Yeoman to build the app. I upload the very basic hello world app and I get plain HTML text withou JavaScript loaded. Console in Chrome says this:

```
Error: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:2627:15
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:2755:39)
    at http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:2632:45
    at getService (http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:2755:39)
    at invoke (http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:2773:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:2805:23)
    at http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:4620:24
    at update (http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:13692:26)
    at http://../scripts/vendor/d10639ae.angular.js:8002:24 d10639ae.angular.js:5526
```

Anybody experiencing the same and knows the way out?

**EDIT:**

```
'use strict';

yoAngApp.controller('MainCtrl',['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
        'HTML5 Boilerplate',
        'AngularJS',
        'Testacular'
    ];

    $scope.records = [{ title : 'one' }, { title : 'two' }, { title : 'three' }, { title : 'four' }];

    $scope.greet = function() {
        ($window.mockWindow || $window).alert('Hello ' + $scope.name);
    }
}]
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ŁukaszBachman suggested, you may use $inject annotation or you may use Inline Annotation if you want to:

1. Keep your dependency annotations close to your function definitions (for better readability).
2. Stay away from polluting global namespace.

```
app.controller('UsersController',
  [
    '$scope', 'UserService', '$location', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, User, $location, $routeParams) {
      $scope.user = User.get({id: $routeParams.id});
      ...
    }
  ]
);
```

Comment: I edited the code as you said and it seems that it doesn't work - same problem(I added the code to my question)...

Comment: You need to use the appropriate annotation in each one of your scripts that are being minimized. Here's a [plunker demonstration](http://plnkr.co/edit/gXitvrhRy35A66z3UoDk) which proves that inline annotation works in minimized scripts. Also, make sure that you are minimizing your angular source in same cycle, so that minified identifiers (e.g. `angular.module` becomes `a.m`) are the same across your app.

Comment: Great, I' glad you guys have figured it out! :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure that you have used code minifier for production server, am I right?

Anyways, the [folks from Angular Js made pretty clear](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) that using minifier can mess up Dependency Injection if it's not done properly. Why this happens? Have a look:

### Dependency Injection vs. Code Minifier

`function MyController($scope, $log) { ... }`

In the snippet above you are making use of implicit DI. Angular sees variable `$scope` and tries to match it with any managed dependency. In this example it will match it to the `$scope` object.

This, however, will not work after code minifying, as the result will look somehow like this:

`function a(b, c) { ... }`

Since variable and function names were minified, Angular cannot know what exactly an "a" is.

### Solution

Use explicit Dependency Injection configuration.

```
var MyController = function($scope, $log) { ... }
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];
```

In this snippet you are defining which dependencies should be resolved by attaching array of their names to special property of controller (or service) called `$inject`. Now Angular will know that it should resolve `$scope` and pass it as first parameter to `MyController`. Then it will resolve `$log` and pass it as second parameter.
It's all possible because minifiers won't modify the contents of string variables.

Comment: What if I initialize controller like this -> `yoAngApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($window, $scope) {` ?