# Launch project in release with minification AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two moudules:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["homeModule"])...

angular.module("homeModule", [])...
```

and if in web config property "*compilation debug="true".."* everything works fine.
But when I build the project in release and "*compilation debug="false".."* 
BundleCollection  collects all JS files in one I have problem.
In log console i see error

> Error: Unknown provider: n from homeModule

My *"app"* module can not find and connect *"homeModule"*.

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly connect the *"homeModule"* module ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular build not working on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496669/angular-build-not-working-on-server)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with AngularJs and minification in general. When defining dependencies you need to use array notation, for example:

```
angular.module("app", ["homeModule"])
       .controller("UsersController", ["$scope", "usersRepository", function($scope, usersRepository) {
    // ... 
}]);
```

or use https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin which makes conversion for you.

Comment: or don't do minification :-) See **A Note on Minification** in the [AngularJS docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Answer (score 0):

I found problem in homeModule.config
Worked code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ["homeModule"]);
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
        {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        }
    ]);


angular.module("homeModule", [])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
    {
        $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: 'ClientApp/Home/Index.html' });
        $routeProvider.when('/home', { templateUrl: 'ClientApp/Home/Index.html' });
    }])
```